# Add a new input language on symbian s60v5 nokia phone

Tags: keyboard, symbian, s60-5th-edition

Has anybody any ideas about how to add a new input language on a symbian s60v5 nokia phone. E.g.: I have nokia 5230.
I'm thinking about the following options but I'm not sure they'll work:

- Adding specific files to the phone's file system
- Writing a virtual keyboard in java/c++
- Manual installation of device's software with the needed language,
  but then you loose all the other languages installed on your phone

These are my suggestions, not more. I don't exactly know how I should realize them.
In every case, thanks a lot!
Have a good time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's solved very easily. Just install SlideIT and the needed language pack from OVI Store. Even SlideIT Demo is enough but I have bought the full version for 3 euro.
Enjoy.
There is also another solution if your phone supports python (maybe it even works).
http://www.symbian-freak.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=32&t=47102

Answer (score 0):

You can't mess around with device software - it resides in read only part of the phone and for most part is unaccessible to you.
Better find a phone that contains the language you need.

Comment: It's solved very easily. Just install SlideIT and the needed language pack from OVI Store. Even SlideIT Demo is enough but I have bought the full version for 3 euro.
Enjoy.
There is also another solution (maybe it even works) if your phone supports python.
http://www.symbian-freak.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=32&t=47102